# QList<int> cannot be used as a model for Repeater

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I have a `QObject` property declared as:

```
Q_PROPERTY( QList< int > keys READ getKeys NOTIFY keysChanged )
```

And in the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#sequence-type-to-javascript-array) it is stated that:

> Certain C++ sequence types are supported transparently in QML as
>   JavaScript Array types.
>
> In particular, QML currently supports:
>
> - QList< int >
>
> ...

However, when I use this property to drive a `Repeater` model:

```
QtObject {
    id: d_
    property var keys: base.proxy.keys // A binding to the C++ keys property
    onKeysChanged: {
        ...
    }
}

Column {
    spacing: 4

    Repeater {
        id: repeater
        model: d_.keys
        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 24
            width: 24
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

The `Repeater` model produces no delegates.  If I query the length of `d_.keys`, it shows the correct quantity, and if I change the property from C++, `d_.onKeyChanged:{}` is triggered — but the `Repeater` never builds anything.

If I change the QML `keys` property to be a JS array:

```
property var keys: [1,2,3]
```

The `Repeater` works as expected.  If I use the C++ property, but manually convert the data to a JS array, it also works as expected:

```
QtObject {
    id: d_
    property var keys: base.proxy.keys

    onKeysChanged: {
        var list = [];
        for ( var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i ) {
            list.push( keys[i] );
        }
        repeater.model = list;
    }
}
```

This strongly indicates that despite what the docs say, `QList<int>` is *not*  equivalent to a JS array.  Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: I know that this doesn't solve the problem at all, but have you tried using a `QVariantList` filled with integers?

Comment: That's actually a good point. `QList<int>` properties seem to not (directly) work for `Repeater` models but JS arrays do. An alternative would be to use `base.proxy.keys.length` for controlling the model which should always work. I would agree to your statement that `QList<int>` is not equivalent to a JS array.

Comment: @skypjack Yes, `QVariantList` works, which I was quite surprised at since I thought the issue was the container rather than its content type.  If you make that an answer/workaround I will accept it.

Comment: Done. I'm going to add more details, too.

Comment: The docs you link to aren't about models though, they just state that these C++ types are "supported transparently in QML as JavaScript Array types". [This](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html) documentation is, and doesn't list `QList<int>` as a valid model.

Comment: I've created https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47767 in an attempt to make it clearer.

Comment: @Mitch Ah, good point, thanks for making the bug report.  Though shouldn't the page you link to also specify that `QVariantList` can be used as a QML model? As that worked for me.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47768 :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object), the `QVariantList` is converted to a JS array, therefore the problem may be the type of the content not the list itself.

That said, I agree with you that the documentation is not clear enough since the `QList` seems to be a valid alternative as well.

Comment: The docs OP linked to aren't about C++ models though, they just state that these C++ types are "supported transparently in QML as JavaScript Array types". [This](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html) documentation is, and doesn't list `QList<int>` as a valid model. But yes, the documentation should state that they aren't fit for use as models if that's the case.