# QML TableView Model Silently Failing?

Tags: c++, qt, model, qml, tableview

**edit: added some clarification**

**Using QML 5.14**

It seems the `model` attribute of TableView does not want to display a `QList<int>`, or any variation of `int`, be it `qint8`, `qint32`, etc. I can make it work with unsigned `QList<uint>`, however I need to keep the negative range of values in my application.

I've found that the information is making it to the qml layer, because when i call:

```
console.log("cfs.amounts is " + cfs.amounts)
console.log("model is " + model)
console.log("modellength is " + model.length)
```

I actually am getting the expected console output of:

```
qml: cfs.amounts is 11,12
qml: model is 11,12
qml: modellength is 2
```

I've ensured the TableView is functional by **directly** passing it data, i.e. `model: [11, 22]` and it displays correctly, i.e. it displays the indexes `0, 1`. However I can't get it to display anything at all when I pass it the `cfs.amounts`, which is a `QList<int>` in c++. So according to the `console.log`, the model data is there, it is correct, it's getting passed from c++ to qml without issues, and the length is good -- the TableView is just failing to display it.

**The only thing I can think of, is that the TableView is silently failing to display arrays of signed integers.** However I may also be completely wrong, because I can't get a `Repeater` item to recognize it in its `model`, neither. I've searched but I can't find any bug reports on this subject. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to get the qml model to recognize the passed `QList<int>` ? This is all in QML 5.14.

**cashflowschedule.h**

```
#ifndef CASHFLOWSCHEDULE_H
#define CASHFLOWSCHEDULE_H

#include "QObject"
#include "QList"

class CashFlowSchedule : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<int> amounts READ amounts)

public:
    CashFlowSchedule() {};
    QList<int> amounts() { return {11,12}; }
};

#endif // CASHFLOWSCHEDULE_H
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import cpps 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    CashFlowSchedule { id: cfs }

    TableView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: cfs.amounts
        delegate: Text { text: index }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("cfs.amounts is " + cfs.amounts)
            console.log("model is " + model)
        }
    }
}
```

**included in the main.cpp**

```
#include "cashflowschedule.h"
...
    qmlRegisterType<CashFlowSchedule>("cpps", 1, 0, "CashFlowSchedule");
...
```

Comment: Right now, you're using `text: index`, which will only show the index. Did you try `text: modelData`?

Comment: Correct. I intend to just display the index. Currently, nothing displays at all with `text: index`

Comment: edit: and also, `text: modelData` behaves similarly.

Comment: QVariantList also has its own inherent flaws... like how it doesn't work at all.

Comment: It really surprises me to say that QList<int> is apparently not supported as a model. Your question is actually a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996582/qlistint-cannot-be-used-as-a-model-for-repeater). Apparently, the only types explicitly supported for models are those found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html). I think it really SHOULD work though. It's strange that it doesn't.

Comment: What problem are you having with QVariantList?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QList<int> cannot be used as a model for Repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996582/qlistint-cannot-be-used-as-a-model-for-repeater)

Comment: Thank you @JarMan. You pointed me in the right direction and indeed, the issue is with QList. I mucked around with QVariantList and resolved another issue i was having with it and I'm good now.

Comment: I answered my own Q, but if you post an answer I'll accept yours and remove mine.

Comment: I also think this question should be kept open, because the verbage I use to describe my issue is different -- and, i believe, much more search-able in the almighty Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QList<int>` is not one of the official supported C++ types used for models (see the list [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html)). A [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47767) exists to clarify the documentation on that point. A QVariantList is a good alternative to use.